# Dealing with large tables performance in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sqlperformance

I have a table `tbl_ECR_ProductData` with nearly 92356143 rows. Weekly 100000 rows are imported into this table.

The table has 16 columns, 2 of those columns make up the primary key, the remaining columns are of type `varchar`.

My question here is when I search the table based on the remaining column values.. its taking a long time, nearly 10 mins.

How can I minimise the time? Please help me on this.. your help is appreciated... Thanks in advance! 
Table structure is as follows

`CREATE TABLE [tbl_ECR_ProductData](
    [Serial Number] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Act Number] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Act Location] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ManufacturerPN] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act Description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act PtNumber] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act Code] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act DateCode] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Pmrl] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act ReceiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Act Channel] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Act Supplier] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [ImportDate] [datetime] NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_ECR_ProductData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Serial Number] ASC,
    [Act Location] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
)`

Comment: 1. Set indexes on the columns you need to search on
2. If you are storing historical information in the table (i.e. rows that you do not need which values have been superseeded by newer rows) delete these rows or move them to a historical values table.

Comment: When running your queries in SQL Server Management Studio, turn on "Include actual execution plan". Review the generated execution plan to see what sub parts of your query takes the longest time. Look for "nested loops" the generally take more time than index scans etc. Try to either 1. rewrite your query to avoid the parts that take long time or 2. set up indexes on that will help perfomance on the long running parts.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to say how to minimise the time without seeing the code. However,these below links should help you find out where the problem is and probaly fix them. I find these very helpful.

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-1/

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/finding-the-causes-of-poor-performance-in-sql-server,-part-2/